# Is there a problem with writing codes or writing codes on Python?

Tags: python, file-management

I want to calculate a class' notes from `Folder.txt` with `note_calculate`. And I can calculate the grades as well. After calculating, I insert in list(Which called `allnames`). After that I took the information from that list to a new txt folder called `Namesandnotes.txt`. The problem starts now. I want to write `Passed Students` and `Failed Students` in a `.txt` folder. "CC" and higher grades should write in `Passed Students.txt`, lower grades should write in `Failed Students.txt`. But in the code, I can't write names and grades from `Namesandgrades.txt` to Passed and Failed. That is my problem.

```
def note_calculate(line):
    line = line[:-1]
    list1 = line.split(",")
    name = list1[0]
    note1 = int(list1[1])
    note2 = int(list1[2])
    final = int(list1[3])
    son = note1 * (3/10) + note2 * (3/10) + final * (4/10)
    passed = []
    failed = []

    if (son >= 90):
        grade = "AA"
    elif (son >= 85):
        grade = "BA"
    elif (son >= 80):

        grade = "BB"
    elif (son >= 75):

        grade = "CB"
    elif (son >= 70):

        grade = "CC"
    elif (son >= 65):

        grade = "DC"
    elif (son >= 60):

        grade = "DD"
    elif (son >= 55):

        grade = "FD"
    else:
        grade = "FF"
    return name +","+ grade



with open("Folder.txt","r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    allnames = list()
    for i in file:
        allnames.append(note_calculate(i))

    with open("Namesandnotes.txt","r+", encoding = "utf-8") as file2:

        for a in allnames:
            file2.write(a + "\n")

with open("Namesandnotes.txt","r", encoding="utf-8") as file3:
    passed = list()
    failed = list()
    text = file3.read()
    print(text)
    for line in file3:
        line = line[:-1]
        line_element = line.split(",")

        if (line_element[1] == "AA"):
            passed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")
        elif (line_element[1] == "BA"):
            passed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")
        elif line_element[1] == "BB":
            passed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")
        elif line_element[1] == "CB":
            passed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")
        elif line_element[1] == "CC":
            passed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")
        else:
            failed.append(line_element[1] + "\n")


    with open("PassedStudents.txt","r+",encoding="utf-8") as file4:
        for x in passed:
            file4.write(x + "\n")
    with open("FailedStudents.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as file5:
        for c in failed:
            file5.write(c + "\n")
```

Comment: What means you "can't write"? What happens? If there is an error message edit the question to show it as properly formatted text.

Comment: @MichaelButscher No, there is no error message. The codes that I wrote, they should take the text from the folder that I opened, and writes the folder that I want. But codes working like nothing. There is no error like I said, but doesn't writes the folder as I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `text = file3.read()`. Once you've done this, the cursor is at the end of the file, so later when you iterate through file3 line by line, there is nothing left to read at the end of the file, and nothing gets written either. Just delete that one line and it should work.

For further debugging, I also recommend putting in prints at other places, so you can see which conditions and loops your code actually enters.

Comment: .Thank your advise first of all. Like you said, I deleted that code and changed "r+" to "w" also. And the program is working well right now after 5 hours ^^. I was tired and stuck into this problem so long. And after your comment a solution poped-out in my head. I could of use " file.seek(0)" , so then I can move the cursor at the beginning of that file. But right now I'm happy with your solution. Thanks again ^^

Comment: Yes, file.seek(0) should work as well if you want to keep file.read(). Happy to be of service and good luck!